# My app crashes when I run it on my phone

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I just started getting into android app programming and I'm learning everything off the internet. But when that happens it's pretty hard to really understand each and every one of the examples and the methods. Anyway, I tried to create an app that when a button is clicked , it shows a countdown timer counting down from 3 to 1 and then it opens an ImageView.

I defined the TextView(for the countdown), the Button and the Imageview in my XML layout but the app would crash when i'd try it on my phone. I removed the imageview and now it starts up
as it should and when I press the button, the countdown is shown.

BTW, when i press the "Graphical layout" Button, the image is shown there.

Is there something wrong with my XML coding for the ImageView that makes it crash?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:text="@string/btnMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />"


<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/idrink"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
    android:src="@drawable/idrink"
    android:contentDescription="Underwater Drinking"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="126dp"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Comment: Your xml seems ok. Can you provide the exception you're getting and some code?

Comment: You have no idea how bad i feel about this but I don't know what an exception is and where i get it :(
But it tells me when I open the app that "Unfortunately, Press Here has stopped"

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
 
   btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
   eText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tview);
  
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    eText.setVisibility(0);
    showTimer(4000);
    
   }
  }); 
 }

Comment: And in the logcat it says: 04-16 10:27:24.069: E/AndroidRuntime(792): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem could be the ImageView you're trying to set is too big. What resolution and size has the 'idrink' image?

Comment: 5184x3456
5 MB
and what u say actually makes sense :D
It was taken with a professional camera lol.
so if i want to use this picture, do i have to find a way to do it by myself or is there something in eclipse that does it for me?

Comment: @sid802 Check the link under loading scaled down version into memory http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: You should resize it to a smaller size using any program you like as Photoshop. I think Eclipse can't do it for you.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, please mark my answer as correct if your problem is solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

A memory leak happens when the application keeps more and more references to objects and never releases them.

try re sizing your image before adding it to layout.

you can do it as below

```
int hgt = yourvalue; // both the values should be in pixels
int wdt = yourvalue; //   
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(largeBitmap, hgt, wdt, true);
```

i think this will solve your problem...